# Searching the table to confirm then updating a table row

Tags: php, mysql

hate to ask because I've been trying to do all of this on my own but it just will not work, i've searched everywhere and it says I'm doing it correctly

```
include "db.inc.php";

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($ip);
$getcount = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM captcha WHERE ip='$ip'");
$resultc = mysql_result($getcount, 0, count);

if($resultc !== "5"){
    #header("Location: index.php");
    echo "don't work";
}else if($resultc == "5"){
    if (!isset($post)){
        $_SESSION['secure'] = substr(str_shuffle($charset), 0, 6);
    }else{
        if ($_SESSION['secure']==$post){
            mysql_query("UPDATE captcha SET count=0 WHERE ip='$ip'");
        }else{
            $error_message = "Incorrect, Try again";
            $_SESSION['secure'] = substr(str_shuffle($charset), 0, 6);
        }
    }
}
```

its searching the table for the matching ip, getting the number in count, if it does not = count it will echo "don't work" if it does it will do the captcha checks, everything in captcha check works except for the UPDATE

What i'm trying to do here is, I've made a custom Captcha which works, what i need to do now is when a users count is 5 which will add 1 to the current number everytime they successfully shrink a URL, I need it to check the db if it is not 5 I do not want them to have access to the captcha page so I need them to be redirected to the index page, if it is 5 it will go through the captcha which works, but I need to reset the count back to 0 after they enter the captcha code correctly, but it will not update the row.

Comment: have you tried `WHERE `ip`='$ip'` - escaping the field name with ` ?

Comment: another point - does the query not work or is it not being executed due to the IF statement?

Comment: its not the if statement before I added the if($resultc !== "5"){ i had a session delete and an echo in the if that the Update query is in and was in, everything in it worked except for the query

Comment: Please check if mysql_query returns false. And if it does, please show us mysql_error() and mysql_errno().

Comment: Maybe you should show a more complete chunk of code.

Comment: that is all the code, and i'll get that error info in the morning

Comment: this is the error and I also showed the don't work in there -- the count in the DB *is* 5, so I know its not working but when it does work I need that "Don't work" not to be there until it goes all the way though. ---
Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 5 in /home/codyl/public_html/tests/tirl/des/captcha.php on line 207
don't work

Comment: Line 207: $resultc = mysql_result($getcount, 0, count);

Answer (score 0):

@cody: you forgot quotes around "count".
Replace:

```
$resultc = mysql_result($getcount, 0, count);
```

with:

```
$resultc = mysql_result($getcount, 0, 'count');
```